# wrap a single line of text in a dynamic div

Tags: html, css

I have this problem with css: a dynamic div contains a single line of text that I need to be wrapped every time the div resizes its width to a smaller size.

But my problem is that the text is inside the table. It is not a pure text, it actually serves as a directory of the contacts somehow like a paging.

Please refer to the images that I have attached for a better view of my problem. I also attached part of the code that I have below. See the attached image for a better understanding of the problem.

I'm not well versed in css, so I'm hoping you can suggest a better layout for this.

Hope you can help me. Thank you! :)

```
<div id="divSearch" style="width:350px">
<p style="word-wrap:break-word;white-space:pre-wrap;">
    <table id="tblGlossary">
        <tr>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="#" >#</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=A'">A</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=B'">B</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=C'">C</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=D'">D</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=E'">E</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=F'">F</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=G'">G</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=H'">H</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=I'">I</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=J'">J</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=K'">K</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=L'">L</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=M'">M</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=N'">N</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=O'">O</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=P'">P</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=Q'">Q</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=R'">R</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=S'">S</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=T'">T</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=U'">U</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=V'">V</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=W'">W</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=X'">X</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=Y'">Y</a></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="glossary"><a href="www.abc.com?tag=Z'">Z</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</p>
</div>
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P2Gmb/ (with `#ccc` background to see the problem)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using a `table` here?

Comment: A table is a block level element and won't reflow with the DIV resizing. Instead consider using an inline item, such as spans, or just using css to style each link's anchor tag and floating them inside their container.

Comment: @thirtydot: actually that table was already there before we decided to make the user control to be resizable. We just need to edit the user control and it so happens that the layout was designed using that table before. Thanks for asking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `<table>` and replaced it with a `<div>` tag:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/P2Gmb/5/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divSearch" style="width:350px">
<p style="word-wrap:break-word;white-space:pre-wrap;">
    <div id="tblGlossary">
            <a href="#">#</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=A'">A</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=B'">B</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=C'">C</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=D'">D</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=E'">E</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=F'">F</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=G'">G</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=H'">H</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=I'">I</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=J'">J</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=K'">K</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=L'">L</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=M'">M</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=N'">N</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=O'">O</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=P'">P</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=Q'">Q</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=R'">R</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=S'">S</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=T'">T</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=U'">U</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=V'">V</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=W'">W</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=X'">X</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=Y'">Y</a>
            <a href="www.abc.com?tag=Z'">Z</a>
    </div>
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#tblGlossary a {
    padding: 0 2px
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just the way I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your entire table with a div without a fixed width:

```
<div id="divGlossary">
    <a href="#" >#</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="www.abc.com?tag=A'">A</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="www.abc.com?tag=B'">B</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="www.abc.com?tag=C'">C</a>
    &nbsp;
...
```

Since you already have the table inside a div, you can use that one.

The word-wrap property does not apply to table cells in the way that you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a table to wrap. Well, I guess you could try to `display: inline` on everything...?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a scrollbar, you can apply the following style :

```
#longlines {
clip : auto;
overflow : scroll;
}
```

that will fix your problem i hope let me know

```
 <div width="10%" style="position: absolute; left: 2%; word-wrap:break-word;"> bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb </div> <div width="86%" style="position: absolute; left: 14%;word-wrap:break-word;"> bbbb </div>
```

**Or**

use `<Span> </span>` around your text